# Number of days in some period of time

Tags: php, datetime

I'm currently developing a script that will calculate lost profits for items that have been out of stock during some period of time.  I'm aware of the DateTime object and I intend to use the diff method in order to calculate the total number of days in the previously-mentioned period of time.  However, I'm not sure I'm doing this correctly.  I've been running a test script that consists of the following:

```
$today = new DateTime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime("today")));
$lastMonth = new DateTime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime("last month")));

$difference = $today->diff($lastMonth)->days;

echo "There's a difference of " . $difference . " days between today and last month, and to test math, I added five: " . ($difference+5);
```

I thought this would just give me a flat number in days but the $difference variable seems to evaluate to 6015.  It's either not formatted correctly or I'm making some other kind of mistake.  All I want to do is store the difference between these two dates in a variable as the number of days.

Comment: Which php version do you use? Using 5.5 the result of your code will be `There's a difference of 31 days between today and last month, and to test math, I added five: 36` and this looks good to me.

Comment: It's 5.3.  I'm guessing that's the issue?

Comment: I just checked your code using 5.3 as well but it gives me the output same as the comment above.

Comment: Okay, I just did some additional checking.  The code is correct and it does give the right results; the problem seems to originate from the test site on which I was running this.  I put it on another one of our sites for a minute just to see if that would help and I had zero issues.

Comment: So what is the solution/explanation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this technically qualifies as an answer, but there's some kind of issue with the site where I tested this script that causes the calculation to produce an incorrect result.  It works fine everywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Try formatting it this way:

```
$today = new DateTime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime("today")));
$lastMonth = new DateTime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime("last month")));
$difference = $today->diff($lastMonth);
echo "There's a difference of " . $difference->format('%R%a days') . " days between today and last month;
```

Comment: This didn't work either.  Now I'm getting results of -6015 and 6.  In addition, it's not something I need to display other than for verification at this stage of development; I just need the number to be correct and stored in a variable because I have to use it to calculate the number of items sold per day over some period of time.